# How to pass scope to AngularStrap $Alert?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm just new in angular and I'm making a customize alert using angularstrap and repeat a data on object using ng-repeat

here is my angular code

```js
let alertExcpetion = $alert({
    placement: 'top-right',
    type: 'warning',
    show: true,
    keyboard: true
    template: 'alert.template.html'
 });
```

and here is the alert.template.html

```html
<div class="alert" ng-class="[type ? 'alert-' + type : null]">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-if="dismissable" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
        <div class="title">
             {{ someScopeTitle }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-alert">
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                        <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
                        <td><a href="#" ng-click="myfunction(student.someObject)">View File</a> {{student.fullname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

after loading the .alert is empty because it didn't read the scope. is there any possible way to pass scope to angularstrap's $alert?

**angular-strap version v2.1.6 - 2015-01-11**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`scope`** to your alert call .

**js**

```
let alertExcpetion = $alert({
    placement: 'top-right',
    type: 'warning',
    show: true,
    keyboard: true
    template: 'alert.template.html',
    scope:$scope
});
```

Comment: already tried it and just getting error from my IDE saying `'scope' does not exist in type 'IAlertOptions'`

Comment: @Liky Could you please create a plunker example?

Comment: I am just using an outdated angular-strap that's why I am having an errors. used your code and it worked. thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you @Liky

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts-usage), you can pass `controller` and `controllerAs` option to the alert modal.

**another.controller.js**

```
let alertExcpetion = $alert({
    placement: 'top-right',
    type: 'warning',
    show: true,
    keyboard: true
    template: 'alert.template.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
 });
```

**modal.controller.js**

```
.controller('ModalController',...

    $scope.someScopeTitle = 'title';

...
```

**alert.template.html**

```
...
<div class="title">
    {{ ctrl.someScopeTitle }}
</div>
...
```

Comment: i'm getting error with controller, btw i'm using angular-strap version v2.1.6. is it because it is not featured in my version?